# Disconnect from current internet connection in Swift 2

Tags: swift, cocoa, reachability

Is it possible to connect and disconnect to some available network connection with swift, cocoa?

///Addition

So.. I found the NSNetworkInterface, but can't understand how to turn it on or off. Need some little example, just explain, what call -> what get

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to connect and disconnect to some available network connection with swift, cocoa?

You can't do any of this on iOS, of course, since your code will never run with sufficient privileges and the necessary frameworks probably aren't available. You asked about Cocoa, though, not Cocoa Touch, so I'm presuming you're talking about MacOS X.

I assume that you mean actually connecting to a network rather than just connecting to some host over an established network. To do that, you need to change the system configuration. It is *possible* to do that, although you'll need to work at a lower level than Cocoa and instead use the SystemConfiguration framework to change the configuration registry. Your code will have to be running with root privileges in order to work, and that alone may make the process untenable depending on your situation. You can find complete instructions and code at [Programmatically changing network configuration on OSX](https://00f.net/2011/08/14/programmatically-changing-network-configuration-on-osx/). Note that the article dates from 2011, so it's possible that things have changed enough that the advice there no longer works, but it will at least point you in the right direction.

The article obviously predates Swift, but I don't see anything there that wouldn't work in Swift.

Comment: So... After 3 hours of searching I found current NetworkInterface, I was reading instruction, but didn't understand, for disconnection I need just clear  my current DNS? And for connect again just put them back and after both actions call SCNetworkInterfaceForceConfigurationRefresh with current interface?

Comment: Still need help ))